# Implicit conversion using an intermediary val and map/flatMap

Tags: scala

I'm having this implicit def to convert an Option[Int] to an Option[String]

```
implicit def optIntOptString(n: Option[Int]): Option[String] = Some(n.get.toString)
```

while this one works:

```
val optIntVal: Option[Int] = Some(3) 
val converted: Option[String] = optIntVal // the 'optIntVal' which is of type Option[Int] gets converted implicitly to Option[String] due to the implicit def 'optIntOptString'
```

this doesn't:

```
val failConv: Option[String] = Some(3)
 found   : Int(3)
 required: String
       val failConv: Option[String] = Some(3)
```

I'm trying to do a conversion without using an intermediary val

My intention is to use the implicit conversion within a map/flatmap function, something like:

```
val someList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
someList.map((num:Int) => {
  val z:Option[String] = Some(num)
  z
})
```

But even with an intermediary val that holds the source type i get an error, seems like the implicit conversion isn't working within the map method:

```
 found   : Int
 required: String
          someList.map((num:Int) => { val z:Option[String] = Some(num); z })
```

Comment: correct intermediary val: `someList.map((num:Int) => { val z = Option(num); z })`.

Comment: @senia thanks! but I already tried with Option(num) instead of Some(num). I get the same mismatch error if i do `List(1, 2, 3).map((num:Int) => { val p:Option[String] = Option(num); p })`. I'm looking to get a List[Option[String]] with my implicit conv def.

Comment: You should probably also change the implementation of the implicit conversion to better handle `None` (just in case): `implicit def optIntOptString(n: Option[Int]): Option[String] = n.map(_.toString)`

Comment: @Shadowlands nice, wasn't thinking of `None` as an `Option`, thanks!

Comment: @zv.diego without `Option[String]`. it's important! If you want to specify types: `someList.map((num:Int) => { val z: Option[Int] = Some(num); z: Option[String] })`

Comment: @senia magic! didn't know that, what is the name for the `z: Option[String]` magic so that I can google it, seems like it's some sort of "casting".

Comment: The name is `type ascription`. It's type safe unlike casting.

Comment: @senia Thanks! Never heard of it. Although, this one doesn't seem to work with `type ascription` and implicit conversion: `val optInt2OptString: Option[String] = Some(3):Option[String]` but this one does: `val optInt2OptString: Option[String] = Some(3).asInstanceOf[Option[String]]` using `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: Don't ever use `asInstanceOf`. Just don't. In this case you'll get an exception on access to content of `Option`: `Some(3).asInstanceOf[Option[String]].get`. You could use this: `val optInt2OptString: Option[String] = Some(3):Option[Int]`

Comment: Or just `val optInt2OptString: Option[String] = Option[Int](3)`

Comment: @senia Couldn't be more grateful with you for all the help, def would love to accept your answer as the best answer!